# Add up column corresponding to same id

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have the following table and I want the sum of DISTINCT srp_id added up like the sum corresponding to the specific srp_id eg.srp_id 321 for s.no 4,6,8,10,11,12 all have srp_id 321,their sum fields shud add up....

Answer (score 1):

A group by should do what you are looking for:

```
SELECT srp_id, SUM(sym)
FROM ???
GROUP BY srp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `group by`

```
select srp_id,sum(field) from table
group by srp_id
```